# Git: how to push regardless of changes elsewhere?

Tags: bitbucket, git

My live site was updated since my last commit, and I haven't made any local changes, so I want to just push everything that's live up to my Git repo.

However, when I try to push from my live site, I get:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username:password@bitbucket.org/myrepo/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I push without doing a pull?

*PS - I tried doing a git pull force from the live server, and it wiped out my previous commits, so I can't do that*

Comment: You're somehow just holding it wrong... Could you be a bit more specific about your setup?

Comment: I have a .git directory on my laptop and on my server, and I can push to the repo from both. Does that clarify anything?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways doing this :
If you wish to really lose all the commits pushed before yours, use "`push -f`" to force erasing the history.
If you wish to keep both commits, you may try a "`git fetch`" and then a "`git rebase`" in order to keep everyone's changes.

Comment: If I run "git fetch" on the live server, it won't overwrite my code with what it fetches?

Comment: A git fetch should only recover the history without merging. Here is what a git pull does : git fetch, then git merge

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. "git rebase" keeps finding conflicts with every single file. I want it to just push the files up and overwrite them without checking for conflicts. Is this not possible to do?

Comment: The best would be to overwrite with a `git push --force` then.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess there's no way of not trashing all of my previous commits. I'm annoyed that Git is so difficult to use!

Comment: Well if you wish to have the history AND the new commits, you will have to resolve the conflicts..